# Edit browser's text field using java

Tags: java, jsoup

Is it possible to edit browser's text field using java? Currently I'm using Jsoup to gather some information about websites so I'm looking for some more options.Could JSoup to this? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by _edit browser text field_? Do you mean you want to set the value of it? In your browser, you see HTML which is just text. It doesn't make sense to edit it from Java.

Comment: You need to give us more requirements and context to what you're trying to do.  This is too ambiguous

Comment: For example, by adding additional text to link in browser text field I can read error message and find database website is using.I would need to insert certain lines to find out more.

Comment: @JohnSmith By "browser text field" do you mean the address bar, or a text input element on a web page?

Comment: I mean adress bar.Sorry if it's not clear enough but my browsers have only one text field by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how JSoup would help here.  JSoup is just a way to parse html.  You could use it to write out some html that has a text field in it with an `input` tag that has a `value` attribute on it.  Then when you render the file in a browser, the page would have that value.  But since you haven't given us very much information, I'm not sure if this is *exactly* what you want to do or *completely* different from what you want to do.

This is probably the last thing you'd want to do (not the first), but you could set the values of a text field using Java's [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

Comment: Sorry, next time I'll describe my question more.Anyway this is what I needed so thank you.